# npm ERR! npm owner add <user>

Tags: npm-install

Could someone tell why I'm getting these errors?

```
npm au build --env prod
npm ERR! Usage: 
npm ERR! npm owner add <user> [<@scope>/]<pkg>
npm ERR! npm owner rm <user> [<@scope>/]<pkg>
npm ERR! npm owner ls [<@scope>/]<pkg>
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! alias: author
```

Thanks, KB

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

Because you used `npm au` which is short for `npm author`.

```
$ npm author --help
npm owner add <user> [<@scope>/]<pkg>
npm owner rm <user> [<@scope>/]<pkg>
npm owner ls [<@scope>/]<pkg>
```

You probably ment to use `npm run build --env prod`.